# How to make a simulated SD card (an image) work together with a real one in Android 2.2?

Tags: android, linux, embedded, android-sdcard

I've managed to simulate a *fake* sdcard on Android 2.2, so that when I don't have a real sdcard, applications that need sdcard will still work. To achieve this, I borrowed some code from the Android-x86 project's extended version of `vold', and did the following:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/data/sdcard.img bs=1024 count=1 seek=1000000 (1GB image, a sparse file)
# busybox losetup /dev/block/loop7 /data/sdcard.img
# newfs_msdos /dev/block/loop7
```

The problem is, when a real sdcard is inserted, I wish to use both of them without switching back and forth between them - namely, a `dual sdcard setup' on a system which only allows one sdcard. How can this be achieved?

---

Personally I'm not quite familiar with the Android system (actually today is my second day working on an Android project). I was told that the 2.2 version only supports one sdcard mounted on "/mnt/sdcard", applications that read/write sdcard will follow this path. I'm not quite sure about this. Can someone please shed me some light on the Android sdcard limitations and how its presence affects applications?

Comment: Please specify how you wish to have the two storage volumes combined, especially how applications unaware of there being a choice will have their writes directed to one or the other.  Once you've decided this you can start looking into implementation possibilities(remember android is just linux with a novel userland on it; normally locked down but apparently not in your case)